# Prove by induction : Show that $2^{(n^2)}\geq n!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

1. Let $n$ be a nonnegative integer. Show that $2^{(n^2)}\geq n!.$

   (1) Use induction to show that  $2^{(n^2+1)}\geq n+1$ for $n\geq 0$.

   (2) Complete your solution, using induction and part (1).

I have a good idea of how to start the problem, but how would one complete the second part of the solution?

Comment: $2^{n^2}$ or $(2^n)^2$ ?

Comment: the first option: 2 to the power of n to the power of 2

Comment: Click on Help, Choose the Help Center. Choose "How Do I Format Mathematics Here?" Read & continue  to the next link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $P(n)$ be the following statment:
$$2^{n^2}\ge n!\,\,\,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$$
It is true for $n=1$: 
$$2\ge 1$$
Assume it is true for $n=k$:
$$2^{k^2}\ge k!$$
Now assume $P(n)$ is true for $n=k+1$:
$$2^{(k+1)^2}\ge (k+1)!$$
$$2^{k^2+2k+1}\ge (k+1)(k!)$$
$$2^{k^2}2^{2k+1}\ge (k+1)(k!)$$
And since $2^{k+1}\ge k+1$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$ we are done.

Answer (score 0):

n=0 is trivial.

Assume 
$$2^{n^2} \geqslant n! $$

Now, $$ 2^{(n+1)^{2}}= 2^{n^2}.2^{2n+1} \geqslant n!2^{2n+1} \geqslant n!(n+1) = (n+1)! $$

Second last line from your part 1 of the question.